# The table head is responding to the hover assigned to the table row?

Tags: css, hover

I've a simple code for styling my table, as seen in this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/tL8hn3w5/), my issue is at hover above the table head, it is taking part of the styling required at the `row` hover, when i hover over the `head` the text became underlined, while I do not need anything to happen.

Is there any mistake in my code, so that the table head is responding the `hover` effect that is assigned to the row only?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Table styling</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no"/>
    <style type="text/css">
            table, th, td {
                font-family: "Trebuchet MS", Arial, sans-serif;
            }
            caption {
                font-size: 150%;
                font-weight: bold;
                margin: 5px;
            }
            table { 
                width: 750px; 
                border-collapse: collapse; 
                margin:50px auto;
                }
            /* Zebra striping */
            tr:nth-of-type(odd) { 
                background: #eee; 
                }
            th { 
                background: #3498db; 
                color: white; 
                font-weight: bold; 
                }
            td, th { 
                padding: 10px; 
                border: 1px solid #ccc; 
                text-align: left; 
                font-size: 18px;
                }
        tfoot td{
            background: green; 
            color: white; 
            font-weight: bold;
        }
            tr:hover {
                    color: yellow;
                    background: orangered;
                    text-decoration: underline !important;
                }
    </style>
<body>

    <table>
    <thead>
            <th>First Name</th>
            <th>Last Name</th>
            <th>Job Title</th>
            <th>Twitter</th>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td data-column="First Name">James</td>
            <td data-column="Last Name">Matman</td>
            <td data-column="Job Title">Chief Sandwich Eater</td>
            <td data-column="Twitter">@james</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td data-column="First Name">Andor</td>
            <td data-column="Last Name">Nagy</td>
            <td data-column="Job Title">Designer</td>
            <td data-column="Twitter">@andornagy</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td data-column="First Name">Tamas</td>
            <td data-column="Last Name">Biro</td>
            <td data-column="Job Title">Game Tester</td>
            <td data-column="Twitter">@tamas</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td data-column="First Name">Zoli</td>
            <td data-column="Last Name">Mastah</td>
            <td data-column="Job Title">Developer</td>
            <td data-column="Twitter">@zoli</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td data-column="First Name">Szabi</td>
            <td data-column="Last Name">Nagy</td>
            <td data-column="Job Title">Chief Sandwich Eater</td>
            <td data-column="Twitter">@szabi</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
    <tfoot>
        <td colspan="3">Total</td>
        <td >4</td>
    </tfoot>
</table>


</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your CSS tells every row to have an underline on hover.  If you only want that effect on the rows in the body, change the CSS to:

```
tbody tr:hover {
                text-decoration: underline !important;
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

please use this css in your style sheet

```
table thead tr:first-child:hover {
 text-decoration: none !important;
}
```